# node js selenium-webdriver save page as

Tags: node.js, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am using the node.js package called [selenium-webdriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver) and Firefox  v52.9.0 on a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian Stretch).

At a certain point I would like to execute the equivalent of the Firefox GUI "Save Page As" function.

I found reference to something like this on [this page](http://www.mantonel.com/tutorials/web-scraping-raspberry-pi-and-python):

```
# Write the output to output.txt 
with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(browser.page_source))
```

The issue here is this guide is using python instead of node. I am not sure how to implement the equivalent code.

I have located [this](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/io/index.html#write) in the documentation, but the docs don't include any example code and I am not sure how to implement the `.write` function. Can anyone explain (or point me to a resource for understanding) how to achieve "Save File" functionality in selenium-webdriver?

It is also worth mentioning that I need the file that is saved to include modifications made to the DOM by some AJAX and Javascript - that it won't be acceptable to simply save the original source of the html document, but it needs to be a representation of the current state of the page.

Here is some code for context:

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

(async function example() {
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
  try {
    await driver.get('http://localhost/mypage.html');
    await driver.sleep(10000);
    /*SOMEHOW SAVE THE PAGE TO A FILE */
  } finally {
    await driver.quit();
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `driver.getPageSource()`

```
try {
    await driver.get('https://google.com');
    await driver.sleep(1000);
    const source = await driver.getPageSource();
    fs.writeFileSync('source.html', source);
} finally {
    await driver.quit();
}
```